# What social policy reduces border growth via culture?

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings, civilization-5-brave-new-world

The city contains a monument that generates +2 culture. However, the net Culture says zero. The tooltip for Culture +0 says "-2 from policies". What policy causes the -2?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JP3P.jpg

This city was originally Ghandi's capital. It was taken over by Ashurbanipal. He offered it to me to induce peace. I annexed it and purchased a Courthouse.

If I purchase a Pagota, which provides +2 culture, the city produces a net +2. Whatever effect is applying the -2 seems to be a flat -2.

Update: Screencaps of current policies and tenets here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT0Cm.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HT0Cm.jpg#1

Comment: Can you post a screencap of your policies? (Click on the culture part of the top bar.) That will go a long way toward being able to determine what's going on.

Comment: There's 2 policies that give flat +2 according to [civfanatics](http://www.civfanatics.com/civ5/socialpolicies), `Military Caste` under `Honor`and `Constitution` under `Freedom`.

Comment: According to [civfanatics again](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=465974) this might be a bug.

Comment: @zpletan Screencap of Policies and Tenets here:
http://imgur.com/OS3M73q,2ZLNu8u
http://imgur.com/OS3M73q,2ZLNu8u#1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bug. It may be related to one of the following links. (Thanks @Jonathan Drapeau)

http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=465974
http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?t=465889